# Why does CouchDB use a random offset between generated UUIDs?

Tags: couchdb, uuid, b-tree

I'm working on an application that stores data in CouchDB and I want to generate UUIDs for new documents within the application, i.e. without using the [_uuid](https://couchdb.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/server/common.html#uuids) API or relying on UUIDs to be generated by CouchDB when the documents are inserted. To do this, I'm going to recreate the default algorithm that CouchDB uses to generate UUIDs, which works as follows:

*A generated UUID consists of two parts, a random prefix and a monotonically increasing suffix. The same prefix is used for as long as the suffix doesn't overflow, if it does, a new random prefix is used. The suffix starts at zero and is increased in random steps between 1 and 0xffe.*

This all seems reasonable, especially the part about the random but constant prefix that allows documents that are inserted at the same time to be stored near each other in the document B-Tree. What I don't understand is why the suffix is increased in random steps instead of just 1 each time. What is the explanation, or a possible explanation, for this decision?

Comment: The more randomness you have, the less chance of a collision - especially when the data is replicated with other nodes in a cluster.

Comment: @MikeChristensen I was also thinking about that but it turns out that choosing random steps actually increases the chance of a collision.

Comment: Dont know answer to original question, but random ids is not going to be helpful in a cluster, it doesnt prevent collisions.  Mysql uses a fixed interleave offset for that situation, which does work well (each server that allows inserts uses its own offset and all servers share an interval size that is > number of servers).

Comment: My intuition is this: The probability that the same prefix is chosen is x times larger when using random steps instead of a step of 1. x is about 2^11 in the case of the algorithm used by CouchDB, judging from the [source code](https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/635022b27cf72efe82bc30f56393070f2b842615/src/couchdb/couch_uuids.erl). The probability of an actual collision, if the same prefix is used twice, is about 1 in both cases.

Comment: @Sari I'm not really interested in the quality of the randomness, as long as collisions are avoided. Avoiding collisions can't be the motivation for choosing a random step. I'm interested in what was the motivation of choosing a random step. I can imagine that it exploits some behavior of B-Trees to gain some performance.